# Cannot install VMWare Tools in VMWare Fusion

Tags: vmware-fusion

I have a Macbook Pro running VMWare Fusion 2 which I use to run Windows XP Pro. For several weeks, the small VMWare Tools icon in the tasktray of the VM had a yellow exclamation point and in the menu, the option "Install VMWare Tools" was available. On several occasions, I would choose this but nothing would happen except the menu choice would change to "Cancel VMWare Tools Install". The VM seemed to be running just fine other wise, with full resolution support, etc. Well, today I went into Control Panel on WinXP Pro, & uninstalled "VMWare Tools" from Add/Remove Programs. After the restart, the VM ran in 640x480. I chose the Install VMWare Tools from the menu & again nothing.

I upgraded to VMWare Fusion 3, hoping that maybe that would solve it but no luck. From VMWare's website, I found a solution to install the VMWare Tools manually from the disk image in the library/Application support/VMWare/ISOImages. When I follow these instructions, the CD/DVD menu states that the virtual disk image is being used, and yet it doesn't show up in "My Computer". I'm at a loss.

Please, if anyone knows what I can do to get VMWare Tools installed, I would truly appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem.

What i did (successfully) was:

1. Make sure that you can see your Mac HD as a shared folder in Windows

2. Under the FINDER, mount the windows.iso disk image from the Library>Apps Support>VMware>Disk images folder

3. It will appear on the Mac desktop as a disk called 'VMWare Tools': don't try to use it yet.

4. Then go in to Windows under VMWF, and navigate to the MAc HD in windows Explorer, and you will find a 'Volumes' folder.

5. Click the triangle and you'll see the VM Ware Tools 'volume'

6. Open that and double click the setup.exe

7. For me that then run the VMWare Tools installer, and hey presto, all installed and no more cross on the VMWare tools symbol.

The 'update tools' button is now greyed out and i'm running 8.2.3 build 204229

Note that the VMWare menu itself still shows a 'Install VMWare Tools' option. No idea why...